# Drupal 8 issue: InvalidArgumentException: The URI '' is invalid

Tags: url, url-routing, drupal-8

I am struggling with this issue:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The URI '' is invalid.
You must use a valid URI scheme. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri() 
(line 284 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this something relating to your custom code? If so, posting your code would be useful. There is also drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing a blank `uri` into the method. It is complaining about missing a scheme (eg. `http://` or `https://`, or an internal scheme eg: `internal:/`)

So either you are explicitly passing a blank, or something isn't being set correctly. However, it does not seem to be null.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue in Drupal 8 site, please make sure your files directory path is set correctly

I my case files path was Private and it was not configured in settings.php.

```
$settings['file_private_path'] = 'sites/default/files/private';
```

Comment: I added above setting in my settings.php and it's working fine.

Comment: Awesome. Your answer saved me a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of the source code for the [fromUri() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x) it would appear as though it throws that error when the PHP [parse_url](https://secure.php.net/parse_url) function returns an empty scheme:

`... elseif (empty($uri_parts['scheme'])) { throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The URI '$uri' is invalid. You must use a valid URI scheme."); ...`

From what I can gather in your question you seem to be providing an empty/null value to the fromUri method which is in turn causing the script to error when it attempts to parse the value. So I'd imagine that you'd need to do some kind of check before passing it to the fromUri function.

An example of how to use this method is helpfully provided in the comments section of the fromUri page: https://api.drupal.org/comment/61905#comment-61905

Answer (score 0):

In case your URI is `public://`, then use:

```
\Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generate($file->getFileUri())
```