# How to add a shortcut link programmatically in Drupal 9?

Tags: shortcut, drupal-9

Trying to add some shortcut link I get this error

**Fatal error: InvalidArgumentException: The URI '' is invalid. You must use a valid URI scheme. in ../core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php:293**

```
use Drupal\shortcut\Entity\Shortcut;
$taxo_shorcut = Shortcut::create([
    'shortcut_set' =>'default',
    'title' =>  'Test',
    'link' =>  'admin/structure/taxonomy',
]);
$taxo_shorcut->save();
```

Any help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drupal 8 issue: InvalidArgumentException: The URI '' is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067337/drupal-8-issue-invalidargumentexception-the-uri-is-invalid)

Answer (score 1):

Build the URI structure correctly with a `uri` key value using the `internal:` scheme:

```
$taxo_shorcut = Shortcut::create([
  'shortcut_set' => 'default',
  'title' => 'Test',
  'link' => [
    'uri' => 'internal:/admin/structure/taxonomy',
  ],
]);
$taxo_shorcut->save();
```